# Inject configuration in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

I'm using Symfony 4 and there is a configuration file which needs to be injected into the command `App\Command\FooCommand` in the form of an array. I have a custom DI extension registered at `App\Kernel::configureContainer()`, which's used to validate the custom configuration file (for the convenience of the development, the config is big and going to be changed frequently during the dev). The constructor of the command is `public function __construct(Foo $foo, array $config)`, I'm expecting the config as the second argument.

Now how do I put this config there? The documentation says about parameters, but it's not a parameter. I was thinking of changing the definition of the command and adding this argument in the `Extension::load` method like this:

```
class FooExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = $this->getConfiguration($configs, $container);
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        //inject the configuration into the command
        $fooCmdDef = $container->getDefinition(FooCommand::class);
        $fooCmdDef->addArgument($config);
    }
}
```

but it ends up with the error

> You have requested a non-existent service "App\Command\FooCommand".

However the command must have been registered as a service automatically.

What am I doing wrong and how to inject this config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access any service in a DI extension Class **because the container was not yet compiled**. For your case is common to create a [Compiler Pass](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/compiler_passes.html) where you will be able to retrieve the needed service and apply any modification to it.

For example you can create a parameter in the container extension on where store the configuration:

```
class FooExtension extends Extension
{
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = $this->getConfiguration($configs, $container);
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        //create a container parameter
        $container->setParameter('your_customized_parameter_name', $config);
    }
}
```

Then retrieve what you need in the compiler pass and then apply some modification:

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;

class YourCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        # retrieve the parameter
        $config = $container->getParameter('your_customized_parameter_name');
        # retrieve the service
        $fooCmdDef = $container->getDefinition(FooCommand::class);
        # inject the configuration
        $fooCmdDef->addArgument($config);

        # or you can also replace an argument
        $fooCmdDef->replaceArgument('$argument', $config);
    }
}
```

Comment: So the only way is to use these service definition manipulations? I was thinking of configuring this in the YML files which would be more neat. Doesn't seems to be possible though.

Comment: @Sergey I'm not sure to understand what you mean with "_I was thinking of configuring this in the YML files which would be more neat._". Inside an extension class (used outside a Symfony bundle) you can only load a configuration file, use a `ConfigurationClass` to validate it's data, but then you need a compiler pass if you need to access any service and make some modification on it using that data. Maybe if you describe better your specific use case I could be more specific.

Comment: I can inject parameters described in the `parameters` section of the configuration into the services referring to them by their names like `%foo.bar%`. In my case I need to inject a whole configuration section, not a parameter. What I meant was whether I can do the same with it, like using the root configuration key in the service arguments array in a yaml file

Comment: @Sergey Ah ok. parameters in the `parameters` section are intended to be mainly used like a `key: value` pairs but can also be `key: [arrays]`. I never used it like this but I think you can put an entire section inside the `parameters` section using a key like `foo: [arrays]` and refer to it in the service argument as you already know `%foo%` . Never tested but should work and without the need to use a `FooExtension` class.